# Cannot find memory leak, possibly due to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments, swiftui

### Problem

I profiled my app and found that I have memory leaks. Unfortunately, I'm unsure how to diagnose it in this case.

Here is what the memory leaks show in `Instruments`:

[image: Instruments - Memory leak]

[image: Instruments - Call tree for leaks]

[image: Instruments - Call tree for leaks (with system libraries)]

---

### Question

It says that the Responsible Libraries are system libraries, does this mean that this leak is a bug, or is it on my part?

- Is my app somehow causing this leak?
- If so, what could possibly cause it? I don't want to post all my app code making for an unreasonable question, so help for where I need to look would be a great help.

---

*I have added tags for `Swift` and `SwiftUI` because it looks like the leak is coming from `SwiftUI` shown in Instruments.*

Comment: A few things. First, I just verified... SceneDelegate **is not** only in SwiftUI. Create a new iOS non-SwiftUI project to see what I mean. (I thought this because that's what's required for iPadOS multi threading). Next, What beta version are you running? If beta 1, does beta 2 fix it? If beta 2, maybe wait until the GM release in August to be concerned?

Comment: @dfd I'm running Xcode `Version 11.0 beta (11M336w)`, and I am using `iPhone XR` in the simulator. I have not got a real device running the app which I can test on. Thank you for any help! 

Comment: Just checked, and Monday's beta 2 download is `11M337n`. Might be worth checking if that changes something.

Comment: @dfd I know I took a while, I caused myself other memory leaks whilst trying other stuff  Anyway, still have that problem with beta 2 so I'm submitting a radar/bug report

Comment: Good luck! I'm sure Apple is paying attention to these reports, particularly if they apply to Xcode and/or SwiftUI. I'm saying that sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in SwiftUI which causes Memory Leak as of Xcode 11 Beta 3. You can also verify this by building a simple app which shows just “Hello World”, the instruments show a leak here also.